# Javascript performance profiing

Tags: javascript, profiling

I would like to see how fast an autosuggest loads. What I'm currently doing is doing a screencast of it and timing it from:

- [Start] = The sound of the keyDown event.
- [End] = When the autosuggest appears.

I then subtract that and convert it from frames to seconds.

Is there a better way to do this using the javascript console or chrome dev tools? Basically I'd like to time it from the `keydown` event to when the autosuggest div changes.

Comment: Why not just check the date or `performance.now()` at those two events?

Comment: @CertainPerformance how? this isn't my application -- I just have it open in a browser (Chrome).

Comment: That does make things more complicated, but you can still listen to keydown events with a userscript, and perhaps either monkeypatch `XMLHttpRequest` (or `fetch`) to check responses, or (better, if possible) use `MutationObserver` on the autosuggest div, is that the sort of thing you're looking for?